# counting element of data table with a condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas table and I am trying to count how many ratings of each film is superior to 3.

This is what I have:

```
      ratings
      user1 user2 user3
film1  3      5     3
film2  3      4     4
film3  1      2     3
```

This is what I would like:

```
      ratings
      user1 user2 user3 top_score
film1  3      5     3      1
film2  3      4     4      2
film3  1      2     3      0
```

I was able to count the number of ratings but I can't seem to add the condition...

Thank you

Comment: Please format your code properly and show an extract of the dataframe

Comment: `df[('ratings', 'top_score')] = df.gt(3).sum(1)`

Answer (score 0):

First convert your data to a numpy array, then use numpy array operations.

For instance you can select elements greater than a value with:

```
array = ...  # The 2-D vector of films and ratings
high_ratings = array > 4  # Returns a boolean array
```

Then sum this on the 1 axis (along users, by film):

```
top_scores = high_ratings.sum(axis=1)  # Returns a 1-D vector here
```